# SNS subscription confirmation token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am AWS SNS, I create a topic and then a subscription to an endpoint in my app.

I receive a POST in the specified endpoint:

```
{"action"=>"confirm", "controller"=>"sns/subscriptions"}


Started POST "/sns/subscriptions/confirm" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-02-07 20:44:49 +0000
Processing by Sns::SubscriptionsController#confirm as HTML
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I am printing `params` as you can see, but there is no token there.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found all the data in `raw_post`:

```
def data
  @data ||= JSON.parse request.raw_post
end
```

This returns a Ruby Hash.